# Software for boosting up RAM in Mac?

Tags: mac

I need a software that can boost up RAM in Mac.

I have used such softwares for Windows.

Are there equivalents for Mac?

Comment: boosting up RAM?  You mean programs like RAMDoubler back in the day? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectix  A link to a Windows equivalent would be useful for this question.

Comment: @Sathya Because the question doesn't say it is for OS X . Anyways I deleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software for windows really just increased the size of the page file.  There isn't a programmatic way to increase your ram size.  You can increase [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) but it's a poor tradeoff since [hard drive seek speed is about 890,000 times slower than RAM.](http://www.terryscomputertips.com/computers/speed-of-virtual-memory-versus-ram/)